# Run a command against an entire batch of files

Tags: batch

I want to run a command line tool that takes a file, manipulates it and exports a new file.  I can use this command just fine for a single file, but would like to make it run through an entire folder of files of a specified extension. I'd like to name the newly created file based on the old file name, but change the first few letters of the file name to something I specify.  Like this:

command newfile_same oldfile_same

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What command is it exactly? Perhaps it has already an option to do such batch operations? If I understood you correctly, the input and output names looks like `*_same` where "same" is literal?

Comment: the command is:   ogr2ogr -clipsrc clipping_polygon.shp output.shp input.shp  .   I'd like the output to use the input file name, but prefix it with whatever I decide (e.g. input is "file.shp" and the output becomes "prefix_file.shp" .   Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change all files in a directory, which have a special extension, you can use another for-Loop:

```
for FILE in *.extension; do
  command "newfile_$FILE" "$FILE";
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a for loop:

```
for FILE in "file1" "file 2" "another file"; do
  command "newfile_$FILE" "$FILE";
done
```